# Sprites off screen doesn't react to SKLightNode

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit

When a sprite leaves the screen it stops casting shadows, which looks really weird when the shadow just disaperes...

Is there any way to force the the sprites to stay "alive" when it leaves the screen off screen?